# Chapter 13 ex 12 and main project 1. Structure and Algorithm in Java by Frank

Tags: java, arraylist

```
     import.util.Arrays;
     public class AList<T> implements ListInterface<T>{
     private T[] list;
     private int numberOfEntries;
     private static final int DEFAILT_INI_CAPACITY=25;
     public AList()
     {
        this(DEFAILT_INI_CAPACIT);
     }
     public AList
     {
       numberOfEntries = 0;
       // the cast is safe because the new array contains null entries
         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] tempList = (T[])new Object[initialCapacity];
      list = tempList;
     }
       public void add(T newEntry) {  
           ensureCapacity();
           list[numberOfEntries] = newEntry;
           numberOfEntries++;
          } // end add

           public int getLength() {
           return numberOfEntries;
            } // end getLength

           public boolean isEmpty() {
           return numberOfEntries == 0; // or getLength() == 0
             } // end isEmpty

              public T[] toArray() {
            // the cast is safe because the new array contains null entries
             @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
             T[] result = (T[])new Object[numberOfEntries];

              for (int index = 0; index < numberOfEntries; index++) {
               result[index] = list[index];
              } // end for

            return result;
            } // end toArray
```

Prolbems from Data Strucutre and Algorithum in Java by Frank.
On chapter 13 exercise 12 I'm stuck on the following:

the following method Reduce the size of the array:

```
             private boolean isTooBig()
```

This method return true if the number if entries in the list is less than half the size of the array and the size of the array is greater than 20.
The second new method creates a new array that is three quarters the size of the current array and then copies the object in the list of the new array:

```
            private void reduceArray()
```

My Attempt:

```
          private boolean isTooBig()
           {
             int half = (2 / getLenght());;
              return ((numberOfEntries < half) && (numberOfEntries > 20));
           }
          private void reduceArray()
           {
             private T[] list2;
             stuck...
           }
```

My question: I do not know what is The array that I am reducing.
 After I reduce the array. I do not know how to copy an ArrayList to another ArrayList.

Also I am stuck on Main project one. 
1) Write a program that thoroughly tests the class AList. 
My attempt:

```
        public class test {
            public static void main(String[] args) 
            {

               AList<integer> listOfInt = new AList<integer>();
                listOfInt.add(1);
                listOfInt.add(2);

             System.out.println(listOfInt);
            }
```

The output is the address of listOfInt, but I want the literal value 1,2 to be printed.

Comment: since there is no reply, i will be working out and be back around 11:20 p.m sept 11 Pacific time..